# Is libsodium xchacha20poly1305 header sensitive?

Tags: encryption, libsodium

I'm using libsodium to encrypt files with xchacha20poly1305 construct. I got everything working correctly by following documentation (https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream.html) but now I'm wondering about the role of header data.

`crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_init_pull` requires the header from `crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_state` that was used when the data was encrypted so how should I treat the header data? Is it same as AES' iv/nonce that it needs and can be to be distributed with the encrypted data as-is or is it secret like the key?

I realize this is most likely a newbie question but since I'm obviously not a crypto expect, I want to make sure I use libsodium and the construct right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty old question, but since it was still waiting for an answer, here it is.

The header is indeed a nonce. It doesn't have to be secret. But it is required so that if the same stream is encrypted twice, both ciphertexts will look completely different.